# Next Empty Cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA. I'm trying to find the next empty cell within a specific row, row 31 as well as a specific range, column B through column M. I need to find the next empty cell within this row as well as within this range of columns. How can I find it? I've seen answers to find the next empty row but this is not what I'm trying to do. I'm brand new to VBA so any feedback to ask  a better question as well as other resources where I can learn is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the **first empty cell** starting from *B31* ??

Comment: Most of the time you first need to find the last cell with data in a row or column to get the next empty cell, check this [Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for? If not can you please elaborate or provide and example of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Find last column in row 31

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim LstCol As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LstCol = .Cells(31, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        MsgBox .Cells(31, LstCol).Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood OP, but I think they're looking for the next empty cell in the range `B31:M31`, not necessarily the last column in the row.  This might work though, depending on how OP's data is given...